# Deploying smart contract using CREATE2, bytecode, salt - getting different addresses on different chains?

Tags: contract-deployment, create2

I would like to deploy the same contract to multiple chains under the same address using `CREATE2`.

DeterministicDeployFactory: https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/create2-an-alternative-to-deriving-contract-addresses

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract DeterministicDeployFactory {
    event Deploy(address addr);

    function deploy(bytes memory bytecode, uint _salt) external {
        address addr;
        assembly {
            addr := create2(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode), _salt)
            if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
        revert(0, 0)
      }
    }

    emit Deploy(addr);
    }
}
```

Sepolia: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x3311fff00a0b7553f127b5b25397e12cb268f919#code

Goerli: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x34d32ac4ed0cef66bbc638781b97fa6b494b98e0#code

Then, I've compiled a simple contract `storage.sol`, the default contract when opening Remix IDE.

The bytecode: `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`

Salt: `17`

Sepolia deploy TX: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xdbe937835979c53b840a5737fe65b9ab93368ff53275e4787cf3ef73fe533a1a

Sepolia deployed storage: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x8C4201833590b5F93c813847b24902bFf7131FDF

Goerli deploy TX: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x4c92195afbfca1630e9d7f73ca13e190e36c19d5d8eff8397d9e4d7b1b104a82

Goerli deployed storage: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xB38f04cb936E19AB9B8F09b15122668c1F9f77e3

---

I do not understand the reason why the deployed address on Sepolia is different than on Goerli.

[image]

[image]

The `DeterministicDeployFactory` bytecode and salt are the same...

## SOLVED

Factory: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x1dd764cf61c8e56ea048374fece83ffa40616569#code

Factory https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x1dd764cf61c8e56ea048374fece83ffa40616569

Storage: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x8bB256467BfE67b8add96002ffe1B05350bFfA57#code

Storage: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x8bB256467BfE67b8add96002ffe1B05350bFfA57#code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deterministic contract address depends upon the factory contract address. In your case, the contract address of `DeterministicDeployFactory`. If the value of `DeterministicDeployFactory` is same in all other chain and of course the smart contract of diterministic contract will be same.

Comment: Sounds like an egg-chicken problem... How would you solve it? How would you deploy the factory to the same address?

Comment: Only solution I think is first you have to do some transactions in all networks  so that the next nonce that your wallet will have x in all network, with that nonce and bytecode you can get same address for `DeterministicDeployFactory`.

Comment: For more detail you check this https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-deploy-a-contract-to-the-same-address-on-multiple-networks

Comment: Thank you for all your comments and support.  I recognize that link, I've included part 2 in my original question. Manually managing nonces does not seem practical. Pretty sure there is a way...

Comment: Yes, just create a new wallet and use it for just the deployment of your factory contract in all chain.

Comment: Magic, thanks, it works! Clever workaround, I didn't realise it is required.